# Recommend button -> post on wall/timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When the user click "Recommend" button on my page, I'd like to post on his wall title and part of the article from my page. How can I change the information which is send to the user wall/timeline? I've found a tip that I should add open graph meta tags, but when I set og:title and og:description in META:

```
<meta content="Title" property="og:title">
<meta content="Description" property="og:description">
```

nothing change.

Any other ideas? Or maybe I do sth wrong?

[Edited]

My code:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
<meta content="Test1" property="og:title">
<meta content="website" property="og:type">
<meta content="*Link to my web page*" property="og:url">
<meta content="*Link to my image*" property="og:image">
<meta content="Description" property="og:description">
<title>Page Title</title>
[...]
</head>
```

In the Object Debugger I get such messages:

### Warnings That Should Be Fixed

> Inferred Property:    The og:url property should be explicitly provided,
>   even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property:    The og:title property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property:    The og:locale property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

### Open Graph Object Properties

> og:url:   *Link to my web page*
>
> og:type:  website
>
> og:title: Page Title
>
> og:updated_time:  1319793567

### Raw Open Graph Document Information

> Canonical URL:    *Link to my web page*

So it seems that the debugger gets only info from my page (e.g. `<title>`), not from Open Graph tags.
What I do wrong?

---

Probably I've found the reason of my problem - I render my page using JavaScript and then I set my META. Is there any way to set META (dynamically) visible for FB?

Comment: Hey, can you provide an example page?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your page through the debug tool at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug ? 
The debug tool clears Facebook's cache of your page as well as checking the syntax of your meta tags.
There are more tags required than the two you listed there

Comment: Yes, I added more tags and test it but the answer of the debugger is strange for me (see above). I don't know why it don't see my Open Graph tags in this case, because in other case it get all informations. But I can't figure out the reason/rule.

Comment: Is the value of the og:url tag pointing to the same URL that the tags are on? the crawler follows that redirect

Comment: I hope so - I set it using window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't dynamically create meta-tags. You need your server to render those meta-tags correctly when facebook decides to probe it (usually soon after a share/like/recommend operation).

**EDIT** : To make it clear -

There is no way to control the rendering of meta tags from the client.
If you want different URLs of your app to have different og:title, og:image etc.. you have to make sure your SERVER serves the html with the right meta tags for each URL.

- Either put all the info you want in the URL in the first place, for example http://example.com/?title=shalom+world&image=shalom.png and then when you serve the page, parse the URL and render the meta-tags correctly OR..
- Have some ID in the URL according to which you will go fetch a corresponding db record and render the head tag of the html you serve with info from that record as meta tags, for example: http://example.com/DB-RECORD-ID-X123

Comment: Sure you can.  I have done it server side, dynamically creating proper og tags.

Comment: @Dallas That's exactly my point, by "dynamically" I meant - with JS, on the client.

Comment: My apologies @ayal gelles .  I was thinking server side dynamic because that's mostly what I'm looking at right now.